# Spring 3 MVC and Tiles 2.2

Tags: spring-mvc, tiles2

I have configured a Spring MVC / Hibernate / Tiles application.  All was working until I introduced the Tiles component.  I believe I have it right but I keep getting "Cannot render a null template" exception

Here is my root-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"

    xsi:schemaLocation=
        "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.acts542.mygunshop" />

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="com.acts542.mygunshop.controller.SecurityInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptors> 

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
    </bean>
     <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mygunshop"/>
        <property name="username" value="mygunshop"/>
        <property name="password" value="sen32164"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <array>
                <value>com.acts542.mygunshop.model</value>
                <value>com.acts542.mygunshop.dao</value>
                <value>com.acts542.mygunshop.service</value>
                <value>com.acts542.mygunshop.controller</value>
            </array>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop> -->
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

</beans>
```

Here is my web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Here is my tile.xml

```
    <!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
    "-//ApacheSoftwareFoundation//DTDTilesConfiguration2.1//EN"
    "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">

    <tiles-definitions>

    <definition name="template" template="WEB-INF/tiles/mainLayout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/menu.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/footer.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name = "content" value="/WEB-INF/views/Login.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name = "Login">
        <put-attribute name = "content" value="/WEB-INF/views/Login" />
    </definition>

    <definition name = "Home" extends="template">
        <put-attribute name = "content" value="/WEB-INF/views/Home" />
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

Here is my mainLayout.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<html>
<head>
    <title>This is a test!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" align="center" width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%" rowspan="3">
                    <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" />
                </td>
                <td width="80%" height="20%">
                    <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width=80% height="60%">
                    <tiles:insertAttribute name="content" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="20%">
                    <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

LoginController.java

```
package com.acts542.mygunshop.controller;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.ObjectError;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.acts542.mygunshop.dto.BusinessMessage;
import com.acts542.mygunshop.dto.LoginDto;
import com.acts542.mygunshop.form.LoginForm;
import com.acts542.mygunshop.service.LoginService;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.validation.Valid;

@Controller
@RequestMapping({"/", "/Login"})
public class LoginController
{
private static final Logger logger  = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginController.class);

LoginService loginService;

@Autowired
public void setLoginService(LoginService loginService)
{
    this.loginService = loginService;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String processGet(Map<String, LoginForm> model)
{
    LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();
    model.put("form", loginForm);
    return "Login";
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processPost(@Valid @ModelAttribute("form") LoginForm form, BindingResult result, HttpSession session)
{
    if (result.hasErrors())
    {
        return "Login";
    }

    LoginDto loginDto = new LoginDto();

    loginDto.setUserName(form.getUserName());
    loginDto.setPassword(form.getPassword());

    loginDto = loginService.loginEmployee(loginDto);

    if(null == loginDto)
    {
        result.addError(new ObjectError("form", "User Not Found"));
        result.addError(new ObjectError("form", "Please Try Again"));
        return "Login";
    }

    if(loginDto.getMessages().hasMessages())
    {
        result.addError(new ObjectError("form", loginDto.getMessages().getMessage()));
        List<BusinessMessage> messages = loginDto.getMessages().getMessages();
        if(null != messages)
        {
            Iterator<BusinessMessage> iterator = messages.iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext())
            {
                result.addError(new ObjectError("form", iterator.next().getMessage()));
            }
        }
        return "Login";
    }

    session.setAttribute("LoggedOnEmployee", loginDto);

    return "redirect:/Home";
}
}
```

Exception

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet appServlet threw exception
org.apache.tiles.impl.InvalidTemplateException: Cannot render a null template
a t    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:51)
at   org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:864)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1665)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Tried everything - except what you guys might add.  Again, everything seemed to be working and wired correctly.  Had the Login render the login page Post the user / password in a form made a return trip tom to the DB and rendered the Home page.  Once I plugged in Tiles, I can't the first page to render.

Answer (score 2):

Is it tiles.xml or tile.xml ?

In tiles.xml are the Login and Home definitions supposed to extend the template definition?

Comment: Do you see any other issues?

Comment: Now I getting this "File &quot;/WEB-INF/tiles/WEB-INF/tiles/mainLayout.jsp&quot; not found"  if I remove WEB-INF/tiles/, then the page can't be found

Comment: try WEB-INF/tiles/mainLayout.jsp without the '/' in the begining.